# Network and Security Associates v.s. CISCO Security Associates

Tags: professional-education, risk-analysis, cisco

My college is expanding the Information Technology department to include Networking and Security as well as the CISCO Security. In my research online I have found different information for each everywhere I have looked. What I am wondering is: in a nutshell what is the difference (beyond one being CISCO focused, I get that much), and which one would be more beneficial. Because they are new programs that haven't been formalized my school cannot give me any information beyond what classes I can take now that are guaranteed to be in them. Thanks.

Comment: I completely understand about needing more information for a better answer, and I would happily provide more if I had it. Since they are future programs, the only thing they know about them is that they are going to be including them in the fall.

Comment: The Cisco class may follow a Cisco certification.  That can be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information we can't tell you which is better. However, by name, I guess the first one is better.

Why? Because it seems to be general whereas the second is only Cisco related.

You can do the first one and then get certified in Cisco.

Comment: Or, another way to put it, one is general, the other is vendor-specific. Vendor-specific security can be wonderful in that it gets into fine details, but it's the fine details in one specific device/software. Unless you are using that vendor's products, it might not be transferrable. General security gives a broader view and might cover areas that the vendor doesn't address.

Comment: The one good thing about vendor-specific training is that the course material tends to be well-written and tested, where a general education programme is dependant on the college's department. It is worth checking out just how good the existing material is.